# Setting up turtle in python

Tags: python

Just importing the turtle module using 'import turtle' doesnt seem to do the trick.

```
import turtle
turtle.right(90)


>>> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'right'
```

please tell me how to setup turtle for python in win8.

Comment: Just trying a low-hanging fruit: is there any other file like `turtle.py` in that directory with your script?

Comment: http://pythonturtle.org/

Comment: @bereal  Nice, I'll bet that's what it is.  That happens to me too sometimes, and I still forget to think of that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't name your file 'turtle.py'  It conflicts with the module.

Answer (score 0):

If the turtle module didn't import, you should have gotten an ImportError on the first line.  But turtle.right(90) should have worked.

Assuming you don't have turtle installed, though, you can download it from [here](http://pythonturtle.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you shouldn't name the file `turtle.py` is because the modules name is the same, and python takes the new file as the module when you import it. Never name your files after module names.

Answer (score -1):

Guy...

You cannot import a direction.. :DD

It's enough when you import Turtle with the command: from turtle import *.